# How could I rewrite my code in professional style?

Tags: plotting, programming, recursion

I reduced my question to the lowest possible for having your ideas:

```
ix[0] = 1;

vay[0] = 1;

h = 0.01 (*step size*)

ix[k_] := vay[k - 1] + ix[k - 1];

vay[k_] := ix[k - 1] - vay[k - 1];

x = Sum[h^n*ix[n], {n, 0, 5}];
y = Sum[h^n*vay[n], {n, 0, 5} ];
```

I must put:

```
x = ix[0] ;
y = vay[0];
```

and repeat it several times and finally plot `x`, `y` by considering step `h`.
by using `For` loop and `AppendTo` I have got result for a small system but for a huge codes it will take more than 2 hours.
I would be honored to see your suggestions about my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) is used to solve recurrence erquations

```
Clear[ix, vay]

eqns = {
   ix[k] == vay[k - 1] + ix[k - 1],
   vay[k] == ix[k - 1] - vay[k - 1],
   ix[0] == 1, vay[0] == 1};

soln = RSolve[eqns,
     {ix[k], vay[k]}, k][[1]] //
   FullSimplify;

ix[k_] = ix[k] /. soln

(*  2^((1/2)*(-3 + k))*(2 + Sqrt[2] + 
      (-1)^k*(-2 + Sqrt[2]))  *)

vay[k_] = vay[k] /. soln

(*  2^(-1 + k/2)*(1 + (-1)^k)  *)
```

Verifying that these functions satisfy the equations

```
eqns // Simplify

(*  {True, True, True, True}  *)

h = 1/100;

Clear[x, y]

x[nmax_] = Sum[h^n ix[n], {n, 0, nmax}] // FullSimplify

(*  (1/4999)*(5100 + 
      (-102 - 101*Sqrt[2] + 
           (-1)^(1 + nmax)*(-102 + 
                101*Sqrt[2]))/
        (2^((3/2)*(1 + nmax))*25^nmax))  *)
```

The sequence converges rapidly to

```
Limit[x[n], n -> Infinity]

(*  5100/4999  *)

% // N

(*  1.0202  *)

y[nmax_] = Sum[h^n vay[n], {n, 0, nmax}] // FullSimplify

(*  (5000 + (-100 - Sqrt[2] + 
           (-1)^(1 + nmax)*(-100 + 
                Sqrt[2]))/
        (2^((3/2)*(1 + nmax))*25^nmax))/
   4999  *)
```

The sequence converges rapidly to

```
Limit[y[n], n -> Infinity]

(*  5000/4999  *)

% // N

(*  1.0002  *)
```

**EDIT:**

Apparently you intend for `ix[0]` and `vay[0]` to vary between iterations, Therefore set them to variables rather than the constants `{1, 1}`.

```
Clear[ix, vay]
eqns = {ix[k] == vay[k - 1] + ix[k - 1], vay[k] == ix[k - 1] - vay[k - 1], 
   ix[0] == ix0, vay[0] == vay0};

soln = RSolve[eqns, {ix[k], vay[k]}, k][[1]] // FullSimplify;

ix[k_] = ix[k] /. soln

(*  2^((1/2)*(-3 + k))*
   (ix0 + Sqrt[2]*ix0 + 
      (-1)^k*((-1 + Sqrt[2])*ix0 - 
           vay0) + vay0)  *)

vay[k_] = vay[k] /. soln

(*  2^((1/2)*(-3 + k))*
   ((1 + (-1)^(1 + k))*ix0 + 
      (-1 + Sqrt[2] + (-1)^k*
             (1 + Sqrt[2]))*vay0)  *)

eqns // Simplify

(*  {True, True, True, True}  *)

h = 1/100;
nmax = 5;
Clear[x, y]

x[ix0_, vay0_] = Sum[h^n ix[n], {n, 0, nmax}] // FullSimplify

(*  (25005001*(101*ix0 + vay0))/
   2500000000  *)

y[ix0_, vay0_] = Sum[h^n vay[n], {n, 0, nmax}] // FullSimplify

(*  (25005001*(ix0 + 99*vay0))/
   2500000000  *)
```

To use the `{x, y}` output pairs as the `{ix0, vay0}` input pairs for the next iteration use [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html)

```
xyData = NestList[{x @@ #, y @@ #} &, {1, 1}, 20] // N

(*  {{1., 1.}, {1.0202, 1.0002}, {1.04062, 1.0006}, {1.06124, 1.0012}, {1.08208, 
  1.002}, {1.10314, 1.003}, {1.12443, 1.00421}, {1.14594, 1.00561}, {1.16769, 
  1.00721}, {1.18968, 1.00902}, {1.21191, 1.01103}, {1.23439, 
  1.01324}, {1.25711, 1.01565}, {1.2801, 1.01827}, {1.30334, 
  1.0211}, {1.32685, 1.02412}, {1.35063, 1.02736}, {1.37469, 
  1.03079}, {1.39902, 1.03444}, {1.42364, 1.03829}, {1.44855, 1.04236}} *)

ListPlot[Transpose[xyData],
 PlotLegends -> {"x", "y"},
 DataRange -> {0, Length[xyData] - 1}]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

To find functions that align with the `x` and `y` sequences, use [`FindSequenceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html)

```
xs[n_] = xyData[[All, 1]] // Rest // FindSequenceFunction[#, n] & // 
  Simplify

(*  (1/(100 + Sqrt[2]))*(2^(-1 - 8*n)*
      (2*7^(2 + n)*
           ((3572143*(100 - Sqrt[2]))/
                9765625)^n - 99*Sqrt[2]*
           ((25005001*(100 - Sqrt[2]))/
                9765625)^n + 
         ((25005001*(100 + Sqrt[2]))/
                9765625)^n*(102 + 
              101*Sqrt[2])))  *)

ys[n_] = xyData[[All, 2]] // Rest // FindSequenceFunction[#, n] & // 
  Simplify

(*  2^(-1 - 8*n)*(25005001/9765625)^n*
   ((100 - Sqrt[2])^n + 
      (100 + Sqrt[2])^n)  *)

Plot[{xs[n], ys[n]}, {n, 0, 20},
 Epilog -> {
   AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Blue,
   Point[Transpose[{Range[0, 20], xyData[[All, 1]]}]],
   Red,
   Point[Transpose[{Range[0, 20], xyData[[All, 2]]}]]},
 PlotLegends -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your comprehensive answer. But how can I repeat this process for having the next x and y (for the next steps)? (In each new process I  have to put small “x” calculated from previous step as an initial condition for new step, i.e. x = ix[0] and y = vay[0].

Comment: You defined `x` and `y` as a `Sum`. I have derived the closed form of these sums as a function of the maximum value of the iterator. `x[0]` is `ix[0]` and `y[0]` is `vay[0]`. Presumably, your steps just increment the arguments to `x` and `y`, To see each step use `x /@ Range[0, 5] // N` and `y /@ Range[0, 5] // N`

Comment: I have tried to guess how you want the iterations performed. See edit.

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you so much.

Comment: While Mathematica does not analytically solve the problem by using RSlove, may you please suggest any other method to solve the problem?any other command to achieve what I would like to?Thank you @BobHanlon

Comment: @Sima - see `EDIT 2`

Comment: Perfect and excellent. Many thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I have two main suggestions, though I think I might not be quite clear on what you are trying to achieve.  First, in your definitions of `ix` and `vay`, if you add an extra part to the right hand side where you use `Set` as *well* as `SetDelayed` you don't need to recalculate every previous step every time, like this:

```
ix[k_] := ix[k] = vay[k - 1] + ix[k - 1];

vay[k_] := vay[k] = ix[k - 1] - vay[k - 1];
```

Next, using functional expressions like `Map`, `Apply` and `Nest` can do calculations significantly faster than loops like `For`.  For example, here is a simple demonstration of a `For` loop vs a `Map`:

```
function[input_] := Sin[input] + Cos[input];

AbsoluteTiming[
 For[
  list1 = {}; iterator1 = 1,
   iterator1 <= 10000, 
  iterator1++,
   AppendTo[list1, function[iterator1]]
  ]
 ]

(*{2.24134, Null}*)

AbsoluteTiming[
 list2 = function /@ Range[10000];
 ]
(*{0.0176008, Null}*)
```

*Note: `/@` is `Map`, and `AbsoluteTiming` tells you how many seconds it takes to calculate the result.*

You can see the map is 200x faster, as well as being easier to write!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. About your first suggestion:
I have to recalculate each step in every round, because as you can see, the initial values are changing in each iteration, depending on the value of x and y, and maybe this is the problem which makes the process take very long time

Comment: I don't see where you change `ix[0]` and `vay[0]` in the code you posted.  It might be useful if you posted your for loop.